# Individual doctorate in Germany – registering from abroad

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, germany

I'm in the process of starting an individual doctorate in Germany and my supervisor is OK with me living (and conducting research; soc. sci.) abroad for the duration of it.

I understand there can be considerable variation from one university to another, but with the exception of needing to show up in person to submit files (diploma, contract, etc.), would anyone know of specific (state-level?) requirements that would necessitate a residency in Germany or German health insurance if I'm not sticking around?

(I'm an EU citizen, and have no funding/am not employed by the university in question.)

Comment: Education in Germany is a state (Länder) issue, so you would have to at least specify the German state to get a complete answer.

Answer (score 7):

All requirements are (must be) listed in the regulations for the award of doctoral degrees (*Promotionsordnung*) of the university. Ask your supervisor for this document. If you are lucky, there even is a translation to English. Keep in mind that residency could be a secondary requirement (e.g., if you need to be enrolled, residency or health insurance might be a requirement for that, or not). I don't expect a residency in Germany is necessary.

However, I suggest you simply ask at the university's graduation office. It's part of their job to answer such questions.

Comment: Good answer. Just to make it explicit: There are no relevant regulations on a state level, OP is fine with fulfilling all requirements given in the *Promotionsordnung* which is individual for each university or faculty.

Comment: @Snijderfrey What I'm unsure of is health insurance. Federal or state regulations might play a role there. I believe universities must acertain that students have health insurance. And some universities require PhD students to be enrolled.

Comment: Yes, but such regulations will be reflected in the *Promotionsordnung*, so for the moment that is all OP needs. It is like you say, secondary requirements may follow. There might also be an international office at the university which is specialized in this kind of problem.